# Если в ссылке есть /en - добавлять активный класс

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

столкнулся с такой проблемой. У меня на лендинге реализована мультиязычность на WordPress. Я хочу сделать подсветку активного языка если сейчас выбрана его версия. То есть если сейчас www.site.ru/en - Подсвечивался en язык (то есть к нему добавлялся класс active ). Пробовал посредствами js, но ничего внятного не получилось. Также пробовал посредством PHP,

```html
<?php get_field('language') == 'ru' ? 'languague__link-active' : '' ?>
```

Этот код вставлял в атрибут class, но он не хочет работать. Подскажите как я могу решить эту проблему?

Comment: Вы бы хоть аддон указали каким пользуетесь, может в его настройках есть что-то

Comment: Никакой аддон не использую, у меня чистый WordPress :)

Comment: ваш подход в целом верен, только проверьте что хранится в `get_field('language')`

Answer (score 0):

Парсить яваскриптом урл страницы. В зависимости от результата добавлять класс к нужному элементу. На псевдокоде:

```
if (урл документа содержит /%язык%) {
    switch(/%язык%)
    case '/en': элементу с /en добавить класс active;
    case '/ru': элементу с /ru добавить класс active;
    case '/sw': элементу с /sw добавить класс active;
}
```

повесить это на onLoad страницы или хотя бы контейнера с активными языками.

Но разве в метатегах страницы язык не указывается?

Comment: Тут все берется с index.php , то есть язык парситься с метатегов не будет. А можете более подробно написать код, я просто не совсем понял то что сверху написано.

Активный класс: 
languague__link-active

Языки: RU, UA, EN

Заранее спасибо огромное!